# 正規表現の読み方がわかりません

Tags: php, 正規表現, wordpress

Wordpressの構築をやっています。
文字を置換する際の正規表現の読み方がわかりません。
理解しようとネットで調べて書いてることはなんとなく分かるのですが、コードに向き合うとわかりません。というか読めません、読めないので意味がわかりません。
特に「/」と「\」の組み合わせがわかりません。
正規表現に書いてることを話し言葉で解説していただけないでしょうか。

```
    $html = preg_replace('/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', '', $html); 
    $html = preg_replace('/class=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]/i', '', $html); 
    $html = preg_replace('/title=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]/i', '', $html); 
    $html = preg_replace('/<a href=".+">/', '', $html); 
    $html = preg_replace('/<\/a>/', '', $html);
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この正規表現はどこから出てきたものでしょうか？(ご自身で考えたもの or 書籍やサイトに載っていたもの等) / 正規表現は読めなくとも、まず「何をしようとしているか」の目的が分かれば読み解くヒントになる気がします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問に記載のコードは`preg_replace`でヒットした文字列を全て削除しています。
（正確には`''`の空文字で置換している状態）
HTMLのタグの中で指定した属性や、Aタグを削除したいんですかね。

---

```
$html = preg_replace('/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', '', $html);
```

`(width|height)`
"()"でグループ化し、"width"もしくは、"height"を選択します。
`="\d*"`
「`=""`」で括られた`\d`(数値)の、`*`(連続最大長)
`\s`
半角空白かタブ文字、もしくは改行のいずれかを選択。
※例(対象となる文字列)：`width="320"`／`height="240"`

---

```
$html = preg_replace('/class=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]/i', '', $html);
```

`[]`
カッコ内の何れかの1文字にヒットする。`[\'"]`（`'`もしくは、`"`）
`[^]`
`^`に続く文字以外の1文字。`[^\'"]`(`'`と`"`以外の文字)
`+`
直前の1文字の連続を最長一致。`([^\'"]+)`(`'`と`"`以外の文字を最長一致。逆に言えば`'`か`"`に当たるまで選択)
`i`
大文字小文字を区別しない
※例(対象となる文字列)：`class="test"`／`class='Sample'`

---

```
$html = preg_replace('/title=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]/i', '', $html);
```

前述と同様
※例(対象となる文字列)：`title="test"`／`title='Sample'`

---

```
$html = preg_replace('/<a href=".+">/', '', $html);
```

`.+`
任意の1文字の連続を最長一致で選択。
仮に`">`が複数回あった場合、一番最後の`">`にあたるまで選択。

※例(対象となる文字列)：`<a href="https://hogehoge.com">`／
`<a href="https://hogehoge.com"></a><a href="https://nexthoge.com">`

---

```
$html = preg_replace('/<\/a>/', '', $html);
```

`<\/a>`
`</a>`を選択

---

メタ文字に衝突するような`/`は、`\`でエスケープし`\/`にします。
`\s`や、`\d`は、「メタ文字」で検索するといいです。

Comment: ありがとうございました、意味がわかりました。
答えはわかっていたのですが、コピペでの解決はやめたくて自分で読めるようになりたくて質問しました。
最後に、最初の/は「\でエスケープし\/にします」の意味を教えていただけますでしょうか。メタタグは検索して調べたんですが、そこだけがわからず、結果、全体を見ても自信を持てない状況でした。

Comment: @PhpHeigh PHPでのエスケープ文字は理解できていますか？それと同じでメタ文字との混同を避けたりや//で括っているので中で/を使うと構文的にそこで終わってしまいます。それを回避するために単なる文字として扱うようエスケープするのです。かなり基本的なことなので、正規表現とか関係なくエスケープ文字で調べた方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: @PhpHeigh もしこの回答で解決できたようでしたら、回答の横にチェックマークがあるので、そちらを選択して承認してください。承認することで質問が解決済みとなります。

Comment: ありがとうございました、やっと理解できました。
始まりの/は/と/の中に正規表現を書くという超基本的な事だったんですね、お恥ずかしい限りです。
記号の検索ばかりしてました。
これを機会に正規表現を読めるように勉強します、本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @PhpHeigh すみません、悩んでいる部分に気づかず少しズレたコメントしていました。
ついでに補足しておきます。正規表現の`/`で括られた命令の部分を`(正規表現)パターン`と言います。
このパターンに対して`i`(大文字小文字を区別しない)など全体のルールを決める修飾子を`パターン修飾子`と言います。

Comment: @Sieg様　いえいえ、こちらの書き方も悪かったと思います。ただわからない時は何をどう説明していいのかもわかりません。ご指摘いただいたことで助かりましたので、これからはコピペに頼らず自分で書けるようがんばります。基調なご意見ありがとうございました。とても参考になりました。